# request size limit in python asyncio http server

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-asyncio

I am writing my web server in python asyncio. I got a problem: I cannot limit the size of the request to the server. My code:

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    # !!!**************************!!!
    # the problem is here. 
    # the asyncio reader class does not provide a way to determine the size of the request.
    # I can only read a certain number of bytes.
    # But how do I know if I have read everything or is there more?
    # !!!**************************!!!
    data = await reader.read(100)

    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(message)
    print(addr)

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I try:

1. call the read method 2 times. First, giving n bytes as an argument, and then n + 1. After compare the results. It doesn't work because the second time the read method blocks the program and hangs
2. inspect the reader class and find the method where the request body is stored

P. S. Еhere is nothing in the official documentation
P. P. S. Sorry if my description is bad. My english is not good :D.

Comment: Why are you writing your own web server instead of using something like [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)? Correctly implementing a web server is a lot of work, and your question indicates that you need to get acquainted with http basics. If it's a learning exercise, then look up the `Content-Length` header and the `chunked` transfer encoding, which might be relevant for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @user4815162342 The content-length header can be spoofed, it is not safe. The request size must be limited. If this is not done, then all threads can simply be occupied with very large requests. I will do this using nginx. But I would also like to restrict it with python so that it works in debug mode. I don't want to use aiohttp because I want my own service to customize it for myself. It's also marketing. Using your own server allows you to retain clients

Comment: Spoofing content-length doesn't really help the attacker, though - if they send a very large value, the server will simply reject the request, and if they send a value too small, the server will just stop reading after the specified amount. More importantly, a conforming server **must** respect content-length, or the connections from the client will just hang -- which is already happening to you when you try to read as much as you can. While you can try and implement your own web server for the reasons you stated, it will be a lot of unnecessary work. Either way, good luck.

Comment: @user4815162342 I understand it. The problem is that if I limit the request size and read the first 5 megabytes, it is not clear if there is more or if this is the whole request.